# Changing data types of multiple pandas dataframes in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have several data frames which I need to convert the datatypes to integers. I tried using a for loop to try and make my code a bit tidier, but after running this and checking the dtypes they don't change. Anyone know why this could be/any work arounds? I think its something to do with creating copies. An example of similar code below:

```
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    df = df.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a nicer why to code this using a function. It's not quite as elegant as I initially hoped with a for loop, but will save me writing out long lists of column names to be changed several times:

```
def to_int(df, cols):
            df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
            return df

df = to_int(df, ['col1', 'col2'])
```

Allows me to change only the data type of the desired columns.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not changing your initial objects, only your variable df.

To change your initial dataframes you could do the following :

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

for i in range(len(df_list)):
    df_list[i] = df_list[i].astype(int)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the dtypes for me

Comment: This should work, but note that this will only modify elements of your df_list, if for example you created your variable df1 earlier and added it to the list afterward, you should check `df_list[0]` instead of df1. If you want to use your initial variable names afterwards, you can attribute those variable values to the ones of the list, i.e. `df1,df2,df3 = df_list`

Comment: Ah ok, I see. I was hoping to find a tidyer/more elegant way to do this instead of writing:  `df1 = df1.astype(int); df2 = df2.astype(int); df3 = df3.astype(int)` etc. Particularly as I have more than 3 dataframes to convert, and some are subset of the dataframes (i.e.only convert these columns of df4) so it was looking a bit messy.  I was just looking to see if there was an alternative/simpler way to do this but it doesn't seem like there is.  Thank you for your help :)